# Test for @future(callout=true) throws System.CalloutException although there are no DML calls or emails

Tags: unit-test, callout, exception, future

When I'm trying to test a method that makes a callout and is annotated @future(callout=true), I'm getting the exception: "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out". I know that this exception happens when mixing callouts with DML operations, but there is no DML in my code. Also, there are no email alerts invoked. When I remove the @future annotation from the method and leave the rest of the code intact, the exception does not occur. I'm using Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() and a HttpCalloutMock.

Comment: Can you post your code here

Comment: Have you set any savepoints? Apparently there is a bug where those cross the transaction boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was some code in @testSetup method that was causing the exception. I'm not sure what exactly, because the methods called there were quite extensive, but after commenting them out the exception went away. What is most interesting, however, was that this exception was appearing only when the callout method was annotated with @future(callout=true). If I removed that annotation, the exception also went away (so I can say that the alternative solution would be to remove the @future annotation or to move the code to a synchronous method called from the @future method and test the synchronous method instead of the @future one).
This needs to be investigated further because I was unable to determine what exact code in @testSetup was causing this - a simple DML calls do not make the exception happen. Maybe there were some other @future methods called somewhere in @testSetup and they executed only when the test method called Test.stopTest()? This needs to be checked some time later.